# Cocoa Touch UITextView setText: method useless

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a UITextView which I create in Interface Builder for an iOS app. I checked (and double checked, and triple checked) that it is properly connected to the outlet in my code. I create a property and synthesize it, and when I run `NSLog(@"%@", myTextView);`, it returns the UITextView's properties, not null. However, when I try calling `[myTextView setText:@"My Text."];`, it doesn't change anything on the view. I have found many people with similar problems like this on Stackoverflow and other places on the internet, however none of the solutions there helped me. I am using Xcode 4.0.2 on Snow Leopard. I am attempting to do this in the `-viewDidLoad` method. What could be causing this issue?

If you need any more information about my code setup, post a comment and I will update this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the whole text view is visible on screen, and that the font color is not the same as your background?

Comment: Just realized that for some reason alpha was at 0...thanks for your help :) :)

Comment: Not quite what I was thinking, but along the same lines - glad you solved it!  BTW for anyone reading including the whole debugger printout of your errant view description can lead to quicker and more exact answers (I think it this case it would have listed the alpha value).

Comment: Yes, it probably would have, however the only thing I was looking for when printing was just that it wasn't null.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the view that is displayed on the screen is not the same view as `myTextView` points to. Check `[myTextView superview]` and make sure it's onscreen. Then look and see if you've accidentally covered it with something. Change other aspects like the `backgroundColor`. Also, check the `frame` and make sure it's not `CGRectZero`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solved the problem, and it ended up that I accidentally set the alpha to 0 :) I will keep your suggestions in mind for the future.